# Enable Scala syntax highlighting for the [scala.js] tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Could you please enable `lang-scala` syntax highlighting on questions tagged with [scala.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala.js)? Scala.js is technically a dialect of Scala, but they have exactly the same syntax.

And, if you think that makes sense, is it possible to have Scala take precedence over JavaScript when both `scala.js` and `javascript` are used? Most Scala.js questions include the `javascript` tag in addition to `scala.js`, because they interop with some JS library, but most of the code is written in Scala.js.

Comment: No to the latter. If there are conflicting non-'default' highlighting-hints, the highlighter always defaults to 'default'.

Comment: OK fair enough. That makes sense.

Comment: @Deduplicator Why not change that in this case?

Comment: @nwp: Special casing for just this case in the SE engine? Make a FR if you are convinced of it, though I personally doubt the ROI would justify that, especially as that would add quite some complexity and there are lots of more important things to do.